# How to generalize this code for multi variable equations?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am a newbie at LISP. I am following Andrew Ng's course for machine learning in Coursera (First week still). I wanted to try doing linear regression in LISP. 
I wrote the code for single-variable linear regression. The code seems to work fine. I want to generalize this for multi-variable linear functions. I want to know how to start doing this. I want to end up with something like :

```
(defun run-linear-regression alpha iterations training-set number-of-variables (...))
```

which would in turn create a hypothesis generator function with input number of variables, partial derivative functions for these hypotheses, etc.

Following is the code I have so far. I do not need anyone to code this for me, but some guidance on how to go about doing what I want would be appreciated. Also, any general comments on how to improve the code (performance, style, etc) I have so far are also welcome.

```
(defun make-hypothesis (theta1 theta2)
  (lambda (x) 
    (+ theta1 (* x theta2))))

(defun make-cost-function (hypothesis)
  (lambda (training-data)
    (let* ((x (car training-data)) (y (cadr training-data))
       (val (- (funcall hypothesis x) y)))
      (* val val))))

(defun make-J-1 (cost-function)
  (lambda (training-set) (float 
              (/ 
               (reduce #'+ (mapcar cost-function training-set)) 
               (* 2 (length training-set))))))


(defun make-J (theta1 theta2)
  (make-J-1 (make-cost-function (make-hypothesis theta1 theta2))))

(defun make-part-deriv-1 (hypothesis)
  (lambda (test-set)
    (let ((m (length test-set)))
      (float (/
          (reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda(elem)(- (funcall hypothesis (car elem)) (cadr elem))) test-set))
          m)))))

(defun make-part-deriv-2 (hypothesis)
  (lambda (test-set)
    (let ((m (length test-set)))
      (float (/
          (reduce #'+ (mapcar (lambda(elem)(* (- (funcall hypothesis (car elem)) (cadr elem)) (funcall hypothesis (car elem)))) test-set))
          m)))))

(defun make-learn-fn (alpha theta1 theta2 make-part-deriv)
  (lambda (test-set) 
    (let* ((hypothesis (make-hypothesis theta1 theta2)) (pdv (funcall make-part-deriv hypothesis)))
      (* alpha (funcall pdv test-set)))))

(defun make-learners (alpha)
  (list 
   (lambda (theta1 theta2 test-set) (- theta1 (funcall (make-learn-fn alpha theta1 theta2 #'make-part-deriv-1) test-set)))
   (lambda (theta1 theta2 test-set) (- theta2 (funcall (make-learn-fn alpha theta1 theta2 #'make-part-deriv-2) test-set)))))

(defun run-linear-regression (alpha iterations training-set &optional (theta1 0) (theta2 0) (printer nil))
  (let ((t1 theta1) (t2 theta2))
    (dotimes (i iterations)
      (if (not (null printer))
      (funcall printer t1 t2))
      (let* ((funcs (make-learners alpha))
         (nt1 (funcall (car funcs) t1 t2 training-set))
         (nt2 (funcall (cadr funcs) t1 t2 training-set)))
    (setq t1 nt1)
    (setq t2 nt2)))
    (list t1 t2)))
```

in the end, I would call it like this:

```
(defvar *training-set* '((15 20) (700 6) (23 15) (19 19) (204 15) (60 150) (87 98) (17 35) (523 29)))
(run-linear-regression 0.0001 1000000 *training-set*)
```

Comment: I haven't looked too deeply into the code yet, but a small improvement: Those `(REDUCE #'+ (MAPCAR #'FUNC LIST))` could be simplified to `(REDUCE #'+ LIST :KEY #'FUNC)`. That way they'll be done in one pass, instead of making a temporary list.

Comment: You're a newbie at Lisp, and you're already using higher-order functions and trying to do machine learning? Way to jump in to the deep end!

Comment: "Newbie at Lisp" -- for that your code is nicely written so far. I'd guess you have experience in other programming languages. Is it the concept of multiple variable regression or the Lisp implementation that you've difficulties with?

Comment: As other have noted, this doesn't look bad.  If it's working already, you might want to take a look at the Code Review site, which might be a better fit for review questions where there isn't a specific problem to debug.   Keep up the good work!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Just some guidance if the O.P. wants to go to [codereview.se]. "Here is my code that does X, how could I have written it better/faster/clearer/etc. ?" Is a great code review question. "Here is my code that does X, how can I extend it to also do Y?" Is not. The question currently has both, so if the O.P. wants to bring it to Code Review, they should edit it appropriately.

Comment: @DanielJour thanks to everyone for kind comments. I specifically have trouble with lisp implementation. If what I've read is correct, I think this is where macros come in. However I have trouble thinking how to generalize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the math here, but since no one else has written better answers, here's some general advice.

You should change `RUN-LINEAR-REGRESSION` to take a list of variables, as well as a list of learner-functions. For example:

```
(defun run-linear-regression (iterations training-set
                              variables learners)
  (let ((vars variables))
    (dotimes (i iterations)
      (setf vars (mapcar (lambda (function)
                           (funcall function vars training-set))
                         learners)))
    vars))
```

That takes the learners as an argument instead of making them in the function. Your original code makes the learners inside a loop, which didn't seem necessary since `MAKE-LEARNERS` only takes `ALPHA` as an argument, and that doesn't ever change, so the resulting learners will always be the same.

We also need to change `MAKE-LEARNERS` so that the lambda-functions will take a list of variables:

```
(defun make-learners (alpha)
  (list (lambda (variables test-set)
          (destructuring-bind (theta1 theta2) variables
            (- theta1 (funcall (make-learn-fn alpha theta1 theta2
                                              #'make-part-deriv-1)
                               test-set))))
        (lambda (variables test-set)
          (destructuring-bind (theta1 theta2) variables
            (- theta2 (funcall (make-learn-fn alpha theta1 theta2
                                              #'make-part-deriv-2)
                               test-set))))))
```

That's pretty much the same as what you had, but it uses [`DESTRUCTURING-BIND`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_destru.htm) to extract `THETA1` and `THETA2` from the list `VARIABLES`. Now we can call `RUN-LINEAR-REGRESSION` like:

```
(run-linear-regression 1000000 *training-set* '(0 0) (make-learners 0.0001))
;=> (42.93504 2.5061023e-4)
```

To add more variables, you would write a suitable version of `MAKE-LEARNERS`. Since I don't know the math, I can't really make an example for that.